# add alt tag to yii2 php

Tags: php, yii2, alt

I am trying to add alt="app logo" to logo to my website with the help of Html::img tag but I keep getting errors on the website.
This is my code:

```
                <?= Html::a(
                    Html::img(Configuration::get(Configuration::APP_LOGO_PATH)),
                    '/'.Yii::$app->language
                , ['class' => 'img-responsive']); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add [`alt`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml#img()-detail) in options

```
 <?= Html::a(Html::img(Configuration::get(Configuration::APP_LOGO_PATH), ['alt' => 'app logo']),
     '/'.Yii::$app->language,
      ['class' => 'img-responsive']
    );
 ?>
```

Comment: Wouldn't that add an alt attribute to the link `Html::a(...)`?

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml#img()-detail): "*The tag options in terms of name-value pairs. These will be rendered as the attributes of the resulting tag.*":

```
Html::img(Configuration::get(Configuration::APP_LOGO_PATH), ['alt' => 'app logo'])
```